# Python3 UnicodeEncodeError when file name to write has croatian characters

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding

I'm writing from pandas to csv like this:

```
df.to_csv(extractpath+'/extract_{}'.format(locname))
```

Now, when locname variable contains croatian characters, I get error

```py
*UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0161' in position 53: ordinal not in range(128)*
```

The only workaround I come up with is this:

```
df.to_csv(extractpath+'/extract_{}'.format(locname.encode('utf-8')))
```

However, although error is now gone, file names are not correct anymore, for example they look like:

```
*extract_b'Vara\xc5\xbedin'* instead of *extract_Varaždin*
```

How can I properly solve the problem?

Comment: I hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/9942822/7994074

Comment: @ParthS007 Unfortunatelly didn't help. I've gone through that question several times and still not sure what I did wrong. The most voted answer tells the OP to do pretty much what I did in my shown attempt. Can you suggest more in detail what to try?

Answer (score 0):

I had wrongly set LANG variable in shell, without realizing it., so when I executed python script from shell script it didn't work. Now is fine after correcting LANG variable.